# Getting series of errors while streaming with RTSP URL in IP camera

Tags: rtsp, ip-camera, opencv, python

I'm using `opencv-python` to get the live stream of IP camera using RTSP. Getting series of errors including video decoding error. Is there a way to get rid of these errors and throw some light in converting the live stream into images without any errors

```
error while decoding MB <some digit>, bytestream -<some no.>
A non-intra slice in an IDR NAL unit. decode_slice_header error. no frame
reference picture missing during reorder. Missing reference picture, default is 65634
non-existing PPS 1 referenced. Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[rtsp @ 0x41e10e0] Undefined type (30)
SEI type 157 size 1464 truncated at 307
```

**Note:** I use `Hikvision 2cd123p-i3`model and I use this URL for stream `rtsp://username:pwd@ip_address:554/Streaming/Channels/101/`